# Convert MySQL date to PostgreSQL date

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, mysqli

**UPDATED (SOLVED)**: '2000-00-00' is not a valid date. You must specify a value for the month and day - i.e. '2000-01-01'

I'm newbie with PostgreSQL. I wonder how to convert a MySQL date (YYYY-MM-DD) to PostgreSQL. What type of value should i use in PostgreSQL to set date like YYYY-MM-DD?

If it is impossible then how can i convert YYYY-MM-DD to a proper value in PHP (what is the proper type\value for PostgreSQL)?

Tnx a lot.

Query example (issue in 2000-00-00)

```
INSERT INTO "user" ("user_uni", "user_id", "name", "city", "country", "sex", "birthday", "referal_id", "social_network", "offer_balance", "customer_balance", "registration_time", "last_visit_time", "last_ip", "banned", "fit_actions", "token", "mail", "neverban", "last_api_request", "notify", "vip", "filters_free", "friends", "rate", "discount", "invite_day", "have_invites", "like_public_day", "have_like_public", "last_login", "suspected", "group_counter", "password") VALUES ('1', '19922', 'Иван Иванов', '243', '1', '1', '1988-01-07', '0', '1', '201.770', '500.000', '1352880961', '13533290', '178.150.243.214', '0', '0', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '100.000', '0', '2000-00-00', '0', '2000-00-00', '0', '13533290', '0', '0', '')
```

Comment: It's the same, I've never used a different format. Please check the manual, it's all there: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html In PHP use the DateTime objects to display in a different format.

Comment: 2000-00-00 isn't a valid date, I don't have that day on my calendar.

Comment: Which MySQL version did this come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't converting MySQL date format to PostgreSQL date format. Both use the ISO date format (YYYY-MM-DD) by default.

The issue is that [older MySQL versions were lax about what is considers a valid date](http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html#1_14). Feb 31st? Sure, no problem. The zero'th date of the zero'th month? Whatever.

Newer versions "fix" this by silently converting invalid dates to `0000-00-00` (which is its self also an invalid date, but MySQL accepts it). In [strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html), which should *always* be used with MySQL, it generates an error instead. See [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

PostgreSQL enforces date validity, so it won't accept `2000-00-00`. That isn't a date, it's nonsense. It also rejects `0000-00-00` which causes lots of problems for MySQL users, since MySQL uses `0000-00-00` as a sort of pseudo-null or NaN for dates, a "valid" date that is not actually valid.

Your best option is to correct these dates before importing your data. If you're using them as a placeholder for unknown dates, use `NULL`. (You'll need to tweak queries that rely on `<`, `>`, `=`, etc, because they'll behave differently).

Comment: Note that the specific faux date `0000-00-00` in MySQL does have a functional equivalent in PostgreSQL: `-infinity`. Like the MySQL value, `-infinity` compares smaller than any real value you can express, but unlike the MySQL value, the Postgres version never behaves as if it were a `NULL`.

Comment: Furthermore, PostgreSQL also has `infinity`, which compares *larger* than any real date you can express. (In MySQL this would presumably be something like `9999-99-99` if it existed, but it doesn’t.) This can be useful for e.g. setting a still-employed employee’s end-of-employment value to `infinity` instead of `NULL` (and then always having to account for the presence of nulls).

Answer (score 1):

[PostgreSQL recommend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5796) that you use the YYYY-MM-DD style for dates, so you shouldn't need to do any conversion.

```
SELECT '2015-04-12';
```

Comment: I cant INSERT data. Error: This value in your SQL Fiddle example is out of range

Comment: Can you post an example query that produces this error?

Comment: added to the first post

Comment: Out of range can only happen when it's really out of range: A date must be a valid date and must be between 4713 BC and 5874897 AD.

Comment: What is "4713 BC"? :) I don't understand how to convent YYYY-MM-DD to 4713 BC

Comment: '2000-00-00' is not a valid date. You must specify a value for the month and day - i.e. '2000-01-01'

Comment: @Yevgen: From wikipedia: Anno Domini (AD or A.D.) and Before Christ (BC or B.C.) are designations used to label or number years used with the Julian and Gregorian calendars.